# Get even numbers from range: Sudo to Ruby

Tags: ruby, sudo

Have generated code in sudo and needed guidance transferring it to ruby.

Sudo:

```
Numbers = array containing 1-10
Even_numbers = empty array

Newmethoddeclaration 
For each num in Numbers
      If num % 2 == 0
         Add num to even_numbers
Print even_numbers.
```

Ruby:

Comment: Do you mean pseudo code?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What does [tag:sudo] have to do with it? This is not valid [tag:sudo] syntax, neither for the `/etc/sudoers` file nor for the `sudo` utility.

Answer (score 5):

Following would be a bit shorter..

```
(1..10).select(&:even?)

=> [2,4,6,8,10]
```

Comment: Enumerables are, easily, within my top three favorite features in ruby. Hope this tidbit can be of use to the OP to go along the right path.

Comment: I love the readability of this solution, but for completeness, I would add this alternative: `(2..10).step(2).to_a`. Some may even prefer the following, although I find it a bit more cryptic: `[*(2..10).step(2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You had it in front of your eyes and could have found an answer with some extra research. But here you go:

```
numbers = (1..10)
even_numbers = []

numbers.each do |n|
  even_numbers << n if n % 2 == 0
end

puts even_numbers
```

This can definitely be simplified with some ruby-sugar, however this is very readable and should be self-explanatory. Maybe you are motivated to make it a one-liner ... until someone else took the fun from it: `.select(&:even)` :)

Comment: Thank you for your perspective. I agree and I had gotten stuck with converting so I asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just get the even numbers, you can just instantiate the end result array using a block initializer:

```
Array.new(5) {|i| 2 * (i + 1)}
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

or if you want to generalize it:

```
def even_array_to(n)
  Array.new(n / 2) {|i| 2 * (i + 1)}
end

even_array_to 10
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```